# What does the RPC call "getmemoryinfo" show?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc, memory

What does the output of the RPC call `getmemoryinfo` actually mean? For example, this is from my node running in Docker. Does that mean the `bitcoind` process inside the container is only using `64272` bytes of memory? That's only 64k, that can't be correct, right?

```
{
  "result": {
    "locked": {
      "used": 64272,
      "free": 1264,
      "total": 65536,
      "locked": 65536,
      "chunks_used": 2002,
      "chunks_free": 2
    }
  },
  "error": null,
  "id": "curltest"
}
```

These are the processes inside the container.

```
/ $ ps -a
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 bitcoind 12:52 bitcoind -zmqpubrawblock=tcp://0.0.0.0:28332 -zmqpubrawtx=tcp://0.0.0.0:28333
   43 bitcoind  0:00 /bin/sh
   51 bitcoind  0:00 ps -a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is reporting the memory statistics of the *locked* memory pool, not all memory used in general.

The locked pool is used to store private keys and other security-sensitive material. Bitcoin Core requests from the OS that the memory used by this locked pool is not swapped out, to prevent it from ending up on a swapfile/swap partition on disk.

Comment: thanks for this info. I see that running `cat /proc/$PID/status  | grep VmLck` returns `VmLck:        64 kB`, which is in-line with the `65536` I saw earlier.